# Run .htaccess on cgi/fastcgi server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a website for an sports club in the area. I always ran it on my own server (apache2) when building and testing it and use .htaccess to make some rewrites. Now the website is going live on their server, only problem is they're running on a cgi/fastcgi server...

I'm not that experienced with that kind of IT terms and modifications, so i hope you'll can help me or give me some advice. What is the best way to make the .htaccess work (and the whole website, which also includes php code)? At the moment the website gives an "(IIS 8.5 Detailed Error) HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error. Also their running PHP7...

Hope somebody can help me!! Thanks!!

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect while under construction
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^my\.ip\.addr\.ess$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !construction\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /construction.html [R=302,L]

# remove .html extensions from the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

# convert html to php without changing the extension
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
```

Comment: Please, share your `.htaccess` code what you have tried.

Comment: It's just a standard .htaccess file and i runs perfect on my apache2 server. I will add it to my first post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CGI or FastCGI.

[`.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) is an Apache HTTP specific means of configuring your HTTP server.

If you want to configure Microsoft Internet Information Server then you have to use the IIS configuration methods, not Apache configuration methods.

(You are trying to configure three completely different things in your Apache configuration file, so I'm not going to look up detailed instructions for the IIS equivalents of all of them).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer!! So basically the .htaccess code will never run on a windows server...?

Comment: A Windows server running Apache HTTPD - yes. IIS? No.

Comment: Aha, so updating the server from IIS to HTTPD would probably fix the problem if i'm right?  If that's possible...

Comment: Changing from IIS to Apache, would cause it to support `.htaccess` configuration files (providing Overrides are enabled in the main configuration).